# Migrating from metaboxes to wp_editor()

Tags: metabox, save-post, wp-editor

I got a client requirement where the editing facilities available in wordpress had to be available for content that was meant to be displayed on the sidebar of a particular post/page.

The content to be displayed was implemented originally using metaboxes which contained a single textarea where content was input as raw HTML and did not have insert/upload facilities.

I have decided to migrate this design to use `wp_editor()` as it gives all the wordpress native editing facilities (without using a metabox as it is not recommended). But I am not sure how to get the entered data and POST it to the backend and then tie into the following action to save the data:

`add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sidebar_content' );`

I was also using the following helper functions:

```
get_post_meta();
add_post_meta();
update_post_meta();
delete_post_meta();
```

I would like to know if there are any such functions to ease the CRUD operations related to this data when using wp_editor().

Thanks in advance.
nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just the same like a regular textarea with the exception of the data being escaped so when you call for the saved data just make sure to decode the html entities using `html_entity_decode` here is a very simple demo class, take a look at how the field is created.

```
if (!class_exists('wp_editor_meta_box')){
        class wp_editor_meta_box{

                public function __construct(){
                        /* Define the custom box */
                        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array($this,'wp_editor__add_custom_box' ));

                        /* Do something with the data entered */
                        add_action( 'save_post', array($this,'wp_editor__save_postdata' ));
                }

                /* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
                function wp_editor__add_custom_box() {
                        add_meta_box( 
                                'wp_editor_box',
                                __( 'WP Editor Box' ),
                                array($this,'wp_editor_meta_box'),
                                'post' 
                        );
                }

                /* Prints the box content */
                function wp_editor_meta_box( $post ) {

                        // Use nonce for verification
                        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wp_editor_nonce' );

                        $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_editor_', false );
                        wp_editor( html_entity_decode($field_value), '_wp_editor_' );
                }

                /* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
                function wp_editor__save_postdata( $post_id ) {

                        // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
                  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
                  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
                          return;

                  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
                  // because save_post can be triggered at other times
                  if ( ( isset ( $_POST['wp_editor_nonce'] ) ) && ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wp_editor_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) )
                          return;

                  // Check permissions
                  if ( ( isset ( $_POST['post_type'] ) ) && ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )  ) {
                        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                                        return;
                                }               
                  }
                        else {
                                if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                                        return;
                                }
                        }

                  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
                        if ( isset ( $_POST['_wp_editor_'] ) ) {
                                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_editor_', $_POST['_wp_editor_'] );
                        }

                }
        }//end class
}//end if

new wp_editor_meta_box();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bainternet. Looks like have been a little mislead by WP saying that wp_editor() should not be used in metaboxes. Then again this is only a problem if I intend to move the metaboxes which is not going to happen in my case. Thanks, nav